# How to broadcast wowza video from one iPad to multiple iPad devices - swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, wowza, broadcasting

I want to broadcast existing videos to multiple users through wowza...

Suppose I want to broadcast any 1 uploaded video (in wowza server) to my multiple users? so how can I do that.. can wowza call any API to start streaming in other users devices? Means when I started streaming video from my application then it should start in other devices also through wowza API.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: @szatmary Ohk.. I was not aware about that..

Comment: Please review the how-to-ask guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about broadcasting (streaming) an MP4 file as a simulated Live stream (playout) or as Video On Demand (VOD)?

Obviously you cannot force devices to start playing a stream. That'd only work if you develop an App that can listen for commands and trigger playback accordingly. Wowza doesn't have such an App, nor any built-in features that can do this.

If you want devices to access a stream on-demand you can simply upload the file to Wowza's content folder. If you want to have a programmed playout, like a TV channel, then you can check out this article: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-schedule-streaming-with-wowza-streaming-engine-streampublisher

(the source code of the plug-in that is used in that article is available from https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-plugin-streampublisher)

Comment: Okies.. it means if I paused the streaming from one of the device then it will not reflect on other devices?

Comment: @Apple, if you play the MP4 file like a TV channel, then pausing the stream on a device in the device's own player won't affect other devices. If you want to allow pause and resume, you should use Wowza nDVR as well (built-in, and easy to enable). For VOD it never makes a difference, because VOD is a separate, on-demand stream for each device anyway.

Comment: Thanks @KBoek, is there any way to achieve global pause through application only?

Comment: Like forcing all viewers to pause at the same time? There's no built-in function for that; you could built such into your App and control your App via a command center, or maybe write a Wowza plug-in that can pause the stream on the server, but not 100% sure how I'd implement that.

Comment: In SDK, there is a callback function with streaming status.. I thought that this is used  for global broadcasting. And now I am able to play video file from VOD but not able to play the same thing in multiple devices.. only streaming in a device

Answer (score 1):

As from your Question, You can broadcast stream successfully and you might have used Wowza Go Coder SDK for doing it.

On Broadcasting live stream, broadcasted videos stored in CONTENT directory which is inside of Stream Engine installation directory structure.

You can find all the streamed videos in it.

Now, You want to broadcast particular stored video then you can do it by loading specific URL for that video. Broadcasting for that Video is not possible but, you can play that particular video as below which will be accessible to all your application users :

In IOS, Link or URL for Videos stored in CONTENT directory is as below :

```
http://[Host Address]:[PORT]/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8

rtsp://[Host Address]:[PORT]/vod/sample.mp4 (In Android)
```

Here, **sample** is the name of your Stream. You have to broadcast live stream video with different stream names so that all videos are accessible.

In this way, you can play stored live stream videos.

Comment: I am able to play video in device using VOD, but what I want is global start and pause means if I played any VOD mp4 then it should start on every device which has opened that broadcasting screen.. and as of now I am facing issue is I am not able to play video in multiple devices..

Comment: Okay. So, That means, You want to broadcast a video which is stored in Content folder. Correct ? If YES, then we can not broadcast that video which is already stored in CONTENT directory. We can just use the link and separate users can play it separately. But, We can broadcast a .mp4 Video from our device. i.e. If the video which is there in our mobile device than We can broadcast it as same as we are broadcasting a live stream. For such Wowza provides us sample for broadcasting .mp4 file in it's SDK sample.

Comment: Ohh.. that's unbelievable.. I have videos with 8 GB size so there is no chance to add videos in app itself and then broadcast.. And about content folder directory if all users have content folder directory path (means with IP address & port number) then they can stream the video right? if YES then also there is a problem right now.. Only 1 device able to stream that content directory video..

Comment: I am just saying that you can broadcast a video from your device. CONTENT folder is in your Wowza Stream Engine's installation directry. Am not talking about CONTENT directory of your or user's device.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication.. I am talking about the same CONTENT folder in wowza engine.. So you say that videos which are in that folder can't be broadcast? If yes then how to broadcast existing videos to multiple users? because you can't store your all videos in application itself right.

Comment: I think your solutions is here : https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-publish-a-video-file-as-a-live-stream and yes We can broadcast the videos stored in content folder.

Comment: I just check this.. looking into it and will update XML file. Let you know once I update file and able to stream in multiple devices. But do you have any idea why its working only in 1 device?

Comment: Hey Dharmesh, need quick help.. should we need to install wowza engine only on servers (AWS or any other cloud)? as of now I installed in my local machine may be that's why facing broadcasting issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196257/discussion-between-dharmesh-shah-and-apple).